# JSON encoder returns Optional()

Tags: json, swift, encoding

I am trying to encode my jsonData. All works fine with one exception - I am receiving as output `Optional(my_json_string)`. But I want to receive only `my_json_string`

When I change `req.httpBody = jsonData` to `req.httpBody! = jsonData`, I am getting an error.

```
do {
    let jsonData = try encoder.encode(self)
    let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
    req.httpBody = jsonData
    print ("httpBody is: ", jsonString)
} catch {
    //TODO:error handling
}
```

How to do it correctly and unwrap my JSON string from optional?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no issue with your code, your encoded JSON isn't Optional. The issue you see is that you are printing the return value of the `String(data:, encoding: )` initializer, which is a failable initializer (it returns `nil` if the encoding you supplied to it is wrong), hence the `Optional` in the print statement.

`JSONEncoder` always produces a valid UTF-8 encoded `String`, so you can safely force unwrap the return value of the initializer by doing

```
let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
```